# Unable to build wasm-pack project - `wasm-opt` download failed

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-wasm, wasm-pack

`wasm-pack` is unable to download the required tools for optimizing `wasm-opt`.

This fails the build. I'm left with only option of disabling wasm optimizations with `wasm-opt = false`.

`$ wasm-pack build`

failed with error

```bash
Error: failed to download from https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/releases/download/version_114/binaryen-version_114-x86_64-linux.tar.gz
To disable `wasm-opt`, add `wasm-opt = false` to your package metadata in your `Cargo.toml`.
```

```bash
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Answer (score 0):

For me issue was Default @SECLEVEL

As I'm sitting behind proxy with weaker security. To work with weaker security Default CipherString was lowered to 1.

When I checked `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

```
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

`wasm-pack` relies on `binary-install` for downloading and installing `wasm-opt`

The root cause was one of the dependency of binary-install.

Check the following dependency graph

`binary-install -> ureq -> rustls`

And `rustls` states

```
For reasons [explained in the manual](https://docs.rs/rustls/latest/rustls/manual/_02_tls_vulnerabilities/index.html), rustls does not and will not support:

SSL1, SSL2, SSL3, TLS1 or TLS1.1.
RC4.
DES or triple DES.
EXPORT ciphersuites.
MAC-then-encrypt ciphersuites.
Ciphersuites without forward secrecy.
Renegotiation.
Kerberos.
Compression.
Discrete-log Diffie-Hellman.
Automatic protocol version downgrade.
```

Please upgrade `DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL`